# Telephone Bill Project: C++

Tags: c++

Alright, I have edited some of the code, so now the question is how it calculates the right final total? I am working on the regular service, and I want it to subtract the 50 free minutes first, then add the extra minutes the user has overused, then multiply the extra minutes by $0.20 and make that into the finaltotal.
And if I have any more mistakes please tell me. I know I have made a lot of mistakes, sorry!
I have a project to do, and here is the requested functionalities list:

- Prompts the user to enter an account number, a service code, and the number of minutes the service was used.

  - Regular: Values are “R” and “r”:

    - $10.00/month
    - First 50 min. are free
    - Charges for over 50 min. are $0.20 per min.
  - Premium: Values are “P” and “p”:

    $25.00/month plus:

    - Calls between 6 - 18 first 75 min are free, after that they’re $0.10 per min
    - Calls between 18 - 6 first 100 min are free, after that they’re $0.05 per min
- If any other character is used then display an error message
- Calculate the total and print the bill (display it out)

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
// VARIABLES //
int accnum, minnum, minnumm;
double total, finaltotal, grandtotal, finaltotall;
char scode;

cout << "Hello, thank you for paying your phone bill." << ends;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;

cout << "Please enter your account number: ";
cin >> accnum ; //Enter some number

cout << "Please enter your service code (r as regular service or p for premium service): ";
cin >> scode ;  //Enter R or r for regular service and P or p for premium service

        ////////////// THIS IS FOR REGULAR SERVICE //////////////

if (scode == 'R' || scode == 'r') {     // Values for Regular service
    cout << "This service provides 50 minutes for phone calls for 50 minutes for free for $10.00 a month, and charge $0.20 every minute over 50 minutes." << endl;
    cout << "How many minutes have you used up?: ";
    cin >> minnum;
    if (minnum > 50) {
        total = minnum * .20;
        finaltotal = total + 10;
        cout << "You have made phone calls over 50 minutes, your total will be " << finaltotal << "." << endl;
        cout << "Your account number is " << accnum << " , with a Regular service. You have used " << minnum << "/50 minutes. Your total is $" << finaltotal << " . Thank you for your time." << endl;    //Displays the acc. #, type of service, # of min the phone service used, and amount due from user
        cout << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "You have not made phone calls over 50 minutes, your total will be $" << finaltotal << "." << endl;
        cout << "Your account number is " << accnum << " , with a Regular service. You have used " << minnum << "/50 minutes. Your total is $" << finaltotal << " . Thank you for your time." << endl; //Displays the acc. #, type of service, # of min the phone service used, and amount due from user
    }

       ////////////// THIS IS FOR PREMIUM SERVICE //////////////

} else if (scode == 'P' || scode == 'p') {  //Values for Premium service
    cout << "This service provides your first 75 minutes phone calls from 6:00 - 18:00, and charge $0.10 for every minute over. Your first 100 minutes for phone calls from 18:00 - 6:00 are free, and charge $0.05 for every minute over." << endl;
    cout << "How many minutes have you used up between 6:00 - 18:00? ";    //Time between 6am - 6pm
    cin >> minnumm;
        if (minnumm > 75) {                  //If # of minutes is over 75
            total = minnumm * .10;           //Then it multiplies total * $.10
            finaltotall = total + 25;   //Then adds the $10/month
            cout << "You have made phone calls over 75 minutes, your total will be $" << finaltotall << "." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "How many minutes have you used up between 18:00 - 6:00? ";  }   //Time between 6pm - 6am
            cin >> minnum;
        if (minnum > 100) {                 //If # of minutes is over 100
            total = minnum * .05;           //Then it multiplies total * $.05
            finaltotal = total + 25;
            //Then adds the $25/month
            cout << "You have made phone calls over 100 minutes, your total will be $" << finaltotal << "." << endl;

            grandtotal = finaltotall + finaltotal;  //Calculates both the 6am-6pm and 6pm-6am totals together
            cout << "Your account number is " << accnum << " , with a Premium service. You have used " << minnumm << "/75 minutes from 6:00-18:00. You have used" << minnum << "/100 from 18:00-6:00. Your total is $" << grandtotal << " . Thank you for your time." << endl; //Displays the acc. #, type of service, # of min the phone service used, and amount due from user
        } else {
            cout << "You have not made phone calls over 100 minutes, your total will be $" << finaltotal << "." << endl;
            cout << "Your account number is " << accnum << " , with a Premium service. You have used " << minnumm << "/75 minutes from 6:00-18:00. You have used " << minnum << "/100 from 18:00-6:00. Your total is " << grandtotal << " . Thank you for your time." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl; } //Displays the acc. #, type of service, # of min the phone service used, and amount due from user

        ////////////// THIS IS IF THEY TYPED IN ANY LETTER OTHER THAN R, r, P, p //////////////

} else {        //If user doesn't type P or R, then this is error message
    cout << "Sorry, that service does not exist. Please try again." << endl;
    cout << endl; }


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: @Brandon, because you should debug your code before asking on StackOverflow

Comment: the expression 'a == <something> && a == <something else>' is always false

Comment: `scode` is a `double` when it should be a `char` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see (and people in follow-up answers might find more errors), the glaring issue is that you have used the **AND** operator instead of the **OR** operator.

This statement:

```
if (scode == 'R' && scode == 'r') {     // Values for Regular service
```

Should be:

```
if (scode == 'R' || scode == 'r') {     // Values for Regular service
```

Similarly, this statement:

```
if (scode == 'P' && scode == 'p') {  //Values for Premium service
```

Should be:

```
if (scode == 'P' || scode == 'p') {  //Values for Premium service
```

A variable can't match two different values at the same time, so the `if` blocks will never be entered when using `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: It's even more glaring than that. take a look at the definition of `scode`.